# Error Compiling Kernel Modules: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel-module

I built a sample hello world kernel module and try to compile it using makefile on ubuntu using 
obj-m = m.o

all:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

clean:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I get error message:

> no such file or directory

Comment: you can find answer [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54249888/13463185) hope be useful

Answer (score 2):

---

A standard kernel module build **Makefile** for hello-1.c :

```
obj-m    := hello-1.o

KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD    := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

......... Will create **hello-1.ko**, hello-1.mod.c, hello-1.mod.o, hello-1.o

---

Comment: I tried the makefile above i got me this error message
makefile:10: *** missing separator.  Stop.