# /lib/modules/<version>/build/ not existent

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a very basic "Hello World" device driver example which is taught in any device driver implementation introductory course. My makefile is as follows:

```
obj-m := hello.o

KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/bulid

PWD := $(shell pwd)

all:
 make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

When I am using the make command, it is showing that /lib/modules/version_no/build/ is not existent. So I entered the directory /lib/modules/version_no and found that there is one directory build but if I use the ls command, it is printed in red colour, which means that the directory is deprecated. It contains one link to ../../../usr/src/version_no, but to my surprise, the version number in that link and the name of the actual folder in /usr/src/ are not same. Can anyone point out what is the issue? I am using centos 6.1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because you have not yet downloaded the linux headers of your particular kernel version.

Assuming your kernel version is `4.15.0-32-generic`, install the required header files using `sudo apt install linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic`

In your case you can get it by
`yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: why no linux-headers-4.4.* in  `apt search` ?